# Margin note over body text

Tags: marginpar, wrapfigure, wrap

I'm interested in putting marginal notes that seems like a post-it in the margin of a document.

No problem at all if they are simply made with `\marginpar` and playing with margin width and separation.

But my question is: how can I make the marginal note wider and make it invade the main body of the document? how will it wrap the body text? Let me clarify with a sample:

```
|   asdfasdfasdfasdfasfs        |
|   sadfasdfasdfasdfasas        |
|   asdfajhdfasfd               |
|   jhfasdjfasdfj +----------+  |
|   asdfasdfasdfa | asdasdfa |  |
|   jkasdfjasdfas | sdfadfas |  |
|   jhfasdjfasdfj +----------+  |
|   asdfajhdfasfd               |
|   asdfasdfasdfasdfasfs        |
|   sadfasdfasdfasdfasas        |
```

I'd be interested in some solution, also considering some aspect I don't know about the `wrapfig` package.

And... what about double sided documents (book class)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to use the `wrapfigure` environment:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\setlength{\wrapoverhang}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\wrapoverhang}{\marginparsep}
\usepackage[left=1in,right=2.5in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{O}{6.3cm}
\vspace{-10pt} %% If needed
This is a margin note getting wrapped with the text and going into margin as well.
In \verb!\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{O}[2cm]{6cm}!, \texttt{[8]} denotes the number of line space in the margin note, \texttt{{O}} is the alignment, \texttt{[2cm]} is amount by which the note goes in to the margin (called over hang) and \texttt{{6cm}} is the width.
\vspace{10pt} %% If needed
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[2-3]
\clearpage
\lipsum[3]
\begin{wrapfigure}[11]{O}{6.3cm}
% \vspace{-10pt} %% If needed
This is a margin note getting wrapped with the text and going into margin as well.
In \verb!\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{O}[2cm]{6cm}!, \texttt{[8]} denotes the number of line space in the margin note, \texttt{{O}} is the alignment, \texttt{[2cm]} is amount by which the note goes in to the margin (called over hang) and \texttt{{6cm}} is the width.
% \vspace{10pt} %% If needed
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[4-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be better to use `\raggedright` for the text inside  `wrapfigure` to prevent ugly inter-word spacing.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: That is true if one has unbreakable wordings like this one. Generally your suggestion is better.

Comment: i'd line to thank you for your detailed explanation. Works like a charm!